# Arrange images into subplots with IPython.display?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

How to display a list of images with IPython.display into subplots ?

I used the following codes:

```
from IPython.display import Image
from IPython.display import display

x1 = Image(url='http://image1.png',width=100,height=100) 
x2 = Image(url='http://image2.png',width=100,height=100) 
x3 = Image(url='http://image3.png',width=100,height=100) 
x4 = Image(url='http://image4.png',width=100,height=100) 

display(x1,x2,x3,x4)
```

It showed the 4 images vertically in the IPython notebook cell.

I would like them to be arranged into a 2x2 array.

Comment: IPython has no built-in facility to display images in a grid. You'll need to either combine them into one image using something like matplotlib or PIL, or construct the HTML to lay them out as you wish and display that.

Comment: I see. Thank you. I'll check out PIL.

Answer (score 1):

If not a requirement to display images inside a code cell, you can use markdown tables to display images in tabular format in a markdown cell.

```
| Col header A                  | Col header B                  |
|:-----------------------------:|:-----------------------------:|
| <img src="http://image1.png"> | <img src="http://image2.png"> |
| <img src="http://image3.png"> | <img src="http://image4.png"> |
```

[image: Outcome].

Comment: Is there a way to do this pythonically using variables or something, instead of hardcoding the image names?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use `subplot` from `matplotlib.pyplot`. To display images, use `imshow` function.